# Issues on running Confluent Schema Registry

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I have created a kafka cluster in separate  three centOS machine. All the Zookeepers and kafka server is running properly.

When i try to run schema registry then the host zookeeper got down, therefore schema registry raised a error like error server died unexpectedly.

For your reference i have configured
kafka store url as like `zookeeper.connect` in kafka server config with comma separated. But no luck. Is there any idea?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you post your config file(s)?

Comment: Does it work if you run it all on a single node? Can you post your Zookeeper log file from the machine on which it dies?